# Ellipsis not showing with fixed div with background color in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-position, ellipsis

Not much to comment here ... I'm trying to set the text-overflow to an ellipsis on a div, while having a fixed div with a background somewhere else on the page, which doesn't seem to be working in Firefox (but does work with Chrome) ... Here's the code :

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.ellipsis {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  asdf
</div>
<div class="ellipsis">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap` for the fixed div.

check the snippet

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 50px;
  
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.ellipsis {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  this is the demo text to rere
</div>
<div class="ellipsis">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to be working ... (still using Firefox)

Comment: Oh, sorry for not mentioning : it works in the code snippet, but not on a blank web page ... I can also see the ellipse in the snippet, but when I copy-paste it into Sublime Text and upload it to my website, it doesn't show up :/

Comment: can you give the link of your website? it would be easier to investigate

Comment: That's all the code right there. I just have the CSS between script tags and the HTML under it, nothing else.

Comment: but if the problem is on the website, we should take a look at it to understand the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138835/discussion-between-lucian-and-tristan-cottam).